# Compare two integers for equality in C++ with unknown int types

Tags: c++

Basically what I want is something simple, a function:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
is_the_same_value(A a, B b)
{
    // return true if A is the same value as B
}
```

This seemingly simple question is is hard as using return a == b fails for int/unsigned mix, 
e.g.

```
is_the_same_value(-1, 0xffffffff)
```

would return true. clang/gcc warn about this: `comparison of integers of different signs`

Using something like `a == b && ((a > 0) == (b > 0))` works but still triggers the compiler warning.

Comment: For me (on my particular architecture), `-1` and `0xffffffff` is the same value, they are the exact same, they have the same bits. Please define what does it mean for two variable to "have the same value". Maybe you want just `return std::is_signed(a) ^ std::is_signed(b) || a == b;` (or something like that)?

Comment: @KamilCuk Only when `int` has 32 bits in a 2's complement environment then I guess.

Comment: @KamilCuk that will unfortenately still trigger the compiler warning for the a == b part. And std::is_signed takes a class a parameter, so A and B here, so int a = 32; usinged b = 32; would return false

Comment: Just cast it to get rid of the warning, `a == A(b)`. hm... `std::common_type` would be better I guess

Comment: `is_same_value` will not be accurate when comparing `-1` with `0xFFFFFFFF`. They may have the same bit pattern, but not value.

Comment: Yes and when the value is not the same the template function should return false. It seems to be a very simple thing and yet I could not come up with a good, warning free solution.

Comment: @plaisthos Doesn't that contradict what you said in the question: "_using return a == b fails for int/unsigned mix_"  "_`is_the_same_value(-1, 0xffffffff)`_" - So you want that to return `false`?

Comment: **No.  Please don't do this.**  This is one of those things that show up on thedailywtf.com all the time. Trying to write your own general equality operator instead of using `==` appropriately with casting is either going to reinvent the wheel (by using a wheel) or just going to be this weird thing that proliferates through a code base for no reason that no one on the team will be able to explain to the next crop of new hires.

Comment: **Continued** It might be one thing to have a helper function for comparing 64-bit signed with 32-bit unsigned and handling negatives for a very specific scenario, but you don't really want a generic template. You'll be tempted to use it for all the wrong reasons and then everyone else will copy you for all the wrong reasons as well.

Comment: Maybe `is_numerically_equal` would be a more accurate name? (At least it implies that the function is not intended to work for arbitrary types, like seeing if `"1"` is the same value as `std::cout`.)

Comment: @KamilCuk "same bits" means the same representation, this does not necessarily mean the same value  (e.g. `5.5f` and `0x40b00000`).  "Same value" is a mathematical thing; a negative number does not have the same value as a positive number . C++ arithmetic is defined in terms of values , not representations .

Comment: I agree on the don't do for any normal circumstances. This problem came actually up for a lot more complex series of templates and classes and involves the data type being able to be specified by a template argument. And those class can be converted from one to another but converting into something that is invalid (as in data loss by integer conversion) should raise an exception. That is why I search for this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::common_type` to remove the warning.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename A, typename B>
bool is_numbers_equal(A a, B b) {
    using C = typename std::common_type<A, B>::type;
    return (a > 0) == (b > 0) && static_cast<C>(a) == static_cast<C>(b);
    // or maybe `... && C(a) == C(b);`
}
```

Well, this looks fun to optimize it for the compiler for types that both are the "same":

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<A>::value &&
    std::is_integral<B>::value &&
    (std::is_signed<A>::value ^ std::is_signed<B>::value)
, bool>::type
is_numbers_equal(A a, B b) {
    using C = typename std::common_type<A, B>::type;
    return (a >= 0) == (b >= 0) && 
        static_cast<C>(a) == static_cast<C>(b);
}

template<typename A, typename B>
typename std::enable_if<
    ! (
        std::is_integral<A>::value &&
        std::is_integral<B>::value &&
        (std::is_signed<A>::value ^ std::is_signed<B>::value)
    )
, bool>::type
is_numbers_equal(A a, B b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Comment: Note that `a >= 0` will be optimized out, whereas `a > 0` will not be.

Comment: The second solution looks like the typical C++ template madness that we are all now used to and defend it as proper :P

Answer (score 1):

For value based comparisons where no implicit conversions (signed/unsigned etc) are allowed, checking for type equality could be an option:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename A, typename B>
bool is_the_same_value(const A&  a, const B& b)
{
    if constexpr(!std::is_same_v<A,B>) return false;
    else return a == b;
}
```

Comment: I don't think they're looking for identical bit pattern. As far as I understand, what they want is mathematical equality. Neither of your functions do that. That said, I'm just guessing since the question doesn't go into depth to explain what they want.

Comment: Yeah, I want to know are those two values the same, I renamed the function is_same_value to do that. Your first function fails for the example `-1, 0xffffffff` given in the question

Comment: @eerorika I just commented on the original post.

Comment: @plaisthos No, it doesn't when `int` is 32 bit: https://godbolt.org/z/Pz72Qi

Comment: @plaisthos I removed my previous suggestions in favour of how I currently interpret your question.

Comment: your updated version returns only true if they have the same type so an uint =4 and int=4 would return false.

Comment: @plaisthos Yes, I thought that it was that you wanted. What was wrong with the bit pattern comparing version I had before?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `std::is_integral` to check whether both types are int? Then convert them to a signed `long long` and then compare them.

Comment: The obvious problem with `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t` springs to mind.

Comment: Conversion from unsigned to signed can be problematic, but you need a number higher than 2^63 which is ridiculously high and will probably suffice for more than 99.9% of everyone who will ever come across this thread.

Comment: What I mean is that you are faced with the same conversion warning as OP - or describe how you'd solve that part.

Comment: @JMRC Saying "will probably suffice for more than 99.9%" is a good way to guarantee that you will run smack into the other 0.1%. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can compare memories:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool is_the_same_value(A a, B b)
{
    return std::memcmp(&a,&b,sizeof(A)) == 0;
    // return true if A is the same value as B
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't say if they have the same value. -1 and 255 are not the same value even if there's some platform where there are two different types and one uses the same memory representation to store -1 as the other uses to store 255.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a hard problem to me. There are enough complications so I would not call the result "simple", but it's far from complex. Just deal with the identified issues one at a time, and make sure things are symmetric with respect to the two parameters.

**Issue 1:** converting a negative value to an unsigned type is bad.
**Issue 2:** comparing different types can cause compiler warnings.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool is_the_same_value(A a, B b)
{
    // Address issue 1 by returning false if exactly one of the parameters
    // is negative.
    if ( a < 0 && b >= 0 )
        return false;
    if ( b < 0 && a >= 0 )
        return false;
    // At this point, either both a and b are negative (hence A and B are signed types)
    // or both are non-negative (hence converting to an unsigned type is fine).

    // Address issue 2 by explicitly casting. Make sure you cast both
    // ways to keep things symmetric.
    return a == static_cast<A>(b)  &&
           b == static_cast<B>(a);
}
```

Sure, there are clever ways to make this code more compact (and less readable), but isn't the compiler supposed to be able to do those optimizations for you?

Comment: Disclaimer: just because something *can* be done, does not mean it *should* be done. People who ignore this warning are liable to be eaten by cloned dinosaurs.